# Optimizing gzipped files for block-level deduplication

Tags: storage, gzip, btrfs, deduplication

I have about 100TiB of compressed gzip data on cloud volumes. On my way to run a block-level dedup (duperemove for btrfs) I find that it was compressed without `-n`, which causes block-level difference of the compressed output for otherwise identical files.

Other than recompressing it all with `gzip -n`, is there any other shortcut to get hundreds of millions of gziped files to "lose" that header? and if I already have to recompress them all, should I look into other optimizations as well, like `--rsyncable` to maximize chances of deduplication?

(The data has very high chances of containing a lot of dupes, we are talking daily full dumps of large database tables)

Comment: In other words, is it possible to make "dedup" ignore the gzip header?  i.e., you don't need to rewrite the files, just ignore the headers in your application.

Comment: since I'm talking about a block-level dedup (same if it was a file-level anyway), I don't see how I can make it ignore the header. it's at the beginning of the stream (as far as I know) and not the end of it, so all the compressed data might look different, not to mention with an offset, which will definitely break the block boundries, even if after a block or two the stream looks the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could use zcat to extract the files, then compute a checksum for each file:

```
for x in *.gz
do
    zcat $x | sha256sum > $x.sum
done
```

then check those *.gz.sum files for dupes. Each time you remove a dupe called "something.gz.sum", also remove the corresponding "something.gz"

Comment: If I was going to do simple hardlinking of entire files, this would probably be a good solution, but like I said in the original post, I'm looking to do a block-level dedup, since I have many daily full backups of the same data, and I hope to find identical blocks within non-identical files (like a dump of a DB table where most of the changes happen at the end of the file and rarely at the top and middle), so this solution is somewhat naiive but could be a nice starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the first half of my question re: chopping of the date/name stamp of a gzip file. no, I have not yet found a ready-made piece of code, but I did find the time to install vbindiff, a visual binary diff tool, and found the header was not compressed, and therefore the actual compressed stream is identical with `gzip` and `gzip -n`, and all that is left it to manipulate a few bytes at the very beginning of the compressed files to get the unified version. a tiny C program will solve my problem, unless someone knows a `sed` for binaries :-)

As for the second part, I'll just have to experiment on a bunch of data. If I have any definite results, I'll post them here.